# XPath 2.0 - select all nodes between 2 elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I have the following XML file:

```
<document>
  <article>
    <head>headline 1</head>
    <text>
      <paragraph>foo</paragraph>
      <paragraph>bar</paragraph>
    </text>
    <date>
      <day>10</day>
      <month>05</month>
      <year>2002</year>
    </date>
    <source>some text</source>
    <portal>ABC</portal>
    <ID number="1"/>
  </article>
  <article>
    <head>headline 2</head>
    <text>
      <paragraph>lorem ipsum</paragraph>
    </text>
    <date>
      <day>10</day>
      <month>05</month>
      <year>2002</year>
    </date>
    <source>another source</source>
    <portal>DEF</portal>
    <ID number="2"/>
  </article>
</document>
```

Now I'd like to return all nodes of each article that occur after the head node
and before the portal node. Therefore I was looking into XPath 2 node comparison (<< and >> operators).

What I have so far is the following, which returns empty:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="/document/article/head/following-sibling::*[. << ./article/portal]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Any ideas how to fix that xpath query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/*/node()[. >> ../head and ../portal >> .]
```

**Here is a complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:sequence select="/*/*/node()[. >> ../head and ../portal >> .]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<document>
    <article>
        <head>headline 1</head>
        <text>
            <paragraph>foo</paragraph>
            <paragraph>bar</paragraph>
        </text>
        <date>
            <day>10</day>
            <month>05</month>
            <year>2002</year>
        </date>
        <source>some text</source>
        <portal>ABC</portal>
        <ID number="1"/>
    </article>
    <article>
        <head>headline 2</head>
        <text>
            <paragraph>lorem ipsum</paragraph>
        </text>
        <date>
            <day>10</day>
            <month>05</month>
            <year>2002</year>
        </date>
        <source>another source</source>
        <portal>DEF</portal>
        <ID number="2"/>
    </article>
</document>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
    <text>
        <paragraph>foo</paragraph>
        <paragraph>bar</paragraph>
    </text>
    <date>
        <day>10</day>
        <month>05</month>
        <year>2002</year>
    </date>
    <source>some text</source>

    <text>
        <paragraph>lorem ipsum</paragraph>
    </text>
    <date>
        <day>10</day>
        <month>05</month>
        <year>2002</year>
    </date>
    <source>another source</source>
```

**Update**:

In a comment Roman Pekar has specified a new requirement: he wants to get all such nodes that are between the *first* `head` and `portal` of each article.

**Of course, this is straightforward** -- just change the above expresssion to:

```
/*/*/node()[. >> ../head[1] and ../portal[1] >> .]
```

Comment: nice one, thank you. I've tried it in SQL, but your example didn't work, so I've changed it bit - `/document/article/*[. >> ../head[1] and . << ../portal[1]]`

Comment: @RomanPekar, The question isn't tagged as "sql" question. SQL Server only implements a dialect (not the standard) of XPath 2.0. If you just copy and paste my code and perform the transformation with *any* compliant XSLT 2.0 processor you must get exactly the same result. I always verify a solution and only then paste it and the actual results into the answer. The only difference b/n your expression and the one in this answer is that you select the nodes only for the first article. No such requirement is there in the question -- in fact you say: "I'd like to return all nodes of *each* article"

Comment: It's not that your answer is incorrect, I've actually upvoted it. It just helps me to create solution that works in SQL too. Actually I've tested it and expression returned me exact same result as your expression. But yes, it's based on assumption that there's only one head and portal elements in each article.

Comment: @RomanPekar, I have updated the answer to implement the new requirement that you defined in your comment.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'M NOT AN ORIGINAL POSTER. Your original answer was correct, I think.

Comment: @RomanPekar, I see. Then How do you know that the OP wanted the selected nodes to be only between the first `portal` and `head` of each article? This obviously isn't so.

Comment: Dimitre, I think this was an (understandable) misunderstanding... @Roman wasn't trying to say that the OP had other requirements than what the OP stated. Rather, Roman was just trying to meet his own new requirement, namely, conforming to SQL's subset/dialect of XPath (and perhaps he didn't know it was a distinct dialect).

Comment: @LarsH, Yes, that's now clear and I have upvoted his answer, too.

Comment: thanks, I ended up using the following xpath query:  
`/document/article/head/following-sibling::*[. >> ../portal]`

Answer (score 2):

A simple XPath 1.0 expression should work for such a case:

```
/document/article/head/following-sibling::*[following-sibling::portal]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm often working with xml in SQL Server, so when I've seen Dimitre Novatchev answer, I've tried it in SSMS. It didn't work, as the XQuery implementation in SQL server is [a statically typed language and does static type checking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190938.aspx), so I've tried to find working in SQL Server form of this expression. Here it is:

```
/document/article/*[. >> ../head[1] and . << ../portal[1]]
```

The full query will be

```
declare @Data xml

select @Data = '
<document>
  <article>
    <head>headline 1</head>
    <text>
      <paragraph>foo</paragraph>
      <paragraph>bar</paragraph>
    </text>
    <date>
      <day>10</day>
      <month>05</month>
      <year>2002</year>
    </date>
    <source>some text</source>
    <portal>ABC</portal>
    <ID number="1"/>
  </article>
  <article>
    <head>headline 2</head>
    <text>
      <paragraph>lorem ipsum</paragraph>
    </text>
    <date>
      <day>10</day>
      <month>05</month>
      <year>2002</year>
    </date>
    <source>another source</source>
    <portal>DEF</portal>
    <ID number="2"/>
  </article>
</document>
'

select @Data.query('/document/article/*[. >> ../head[1] and . << ../portal[1]]')
```

Comment: If you made this modification solely for the purpose of having it work in SQL, it would be helpful to state that, because otherwise (in standard XPath), it seems that this answer is not useful to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got a nice suggestion not using `<<` at all but if you want to use it I think `<xsl:copy-of select="/document/article/head/following-sibling::*[. << parent::article/portal]"/>` fixes your attempt.